# Getting columns from a join that is within another join to show up in output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2016.

Here is part of my query (the only part that matters for this) with some unnecessary columns removed:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    S.Status, 
    DT.scheduledstartdate 
    DT.actualstartdate
    DT.scheduledenddate
    MAX(CASE DD.Detail WHEN 'Note' THEN DD.Value END) Notes,
    MAX(CASE DD.Detail WHEN 'Late' THEN DD.[Value] END) Reason,
FROM
    dbo.View_RptMod S 
JOIN 
    [dbo].[View_Phase] P ON P.Studyd = S.Studyd 
JOIN 
    [dbo].[View_Prop] VP ON VP.[Studyd] = S.Studyd
JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         [RowId], [actualstartdate], [scheduledstartdate],[scheduledenddate], [comments]
     FROM 
         [dbo].[DataInfo] DT  
     JOIN 
         (SELECT [RowId], [Detail], [Value] 
          FROM dbo.DataDetail) DD ON DD.RowId = DT.RowId
     WHERE 
         [scheduledstartdate] IS NOT NULL) DT ON DT.PhaseRowId = P.phaserowid
```

As you can see I am doing a lot of joins. If I remove

```
   MAX(CASE DD.Detail WHEN 'Note' THEN DD.Value END) Notes,
   MAX(CASE DD.Detail WHEN 'Reason' THEN DD.Value END) Reasons,
```

from the top part of my query that selects all the variables in the entire query, it runs without issue but I am then missing two columns that I need. I am getting an error:

> The multi-part identifier "DD.Detail"/"DD.Value" could not be bound

when I run it with the `MAX(CASE...)` statements. I have tried running it with without "DD." (just Detail/Value alone) but same error message pops up.

The two `MAX(CASE...)` statements pretty much do what a pivot does whereby I get the info from a column and "create" another column based off those values.

I have already googled this error message and am wondering if maybe I just don't understand but, how do I properly call a column from a join that is inside another join statement, so that when I run the query, that column appears in the output?

Without `MAX(CASE....)` my output looks like this:

| Status | scheduledstartdate | actualstartdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Closed | 2019-01-01 | 2021-01-01 |
| Open | 2021-10-31 | 2021-09-10 |

What I would like my output to look like (with MAX(CASE...) or similar) is like this:

| Status | scheduledstartdate | actualstartdate | Notes | Reasons |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Closed | 2019-01-01 | 2021-01-01 | Another Note | second reason |
| Open | 2021-10-31 | 2021-09-10 | third note | third reason |

Seen people with this error message on here but I haven't found one that ends up being similar to what I am doing, unless again, I am just not understanding this properly. Have seen some say schema `[dbo]` might be wrong but if I remove this, I still get the error message.

Comment: It's because the DD subquery is in the DT subquery.  Therefore DD isn't visible in the outer query. Add DD.Detail in DT, then use DT.Detail in the MAX

Comment: Almost surely the use of DISTINCT has no meaning or effect since you have aggregates and you must group by all non-aggregated columns. That will guarantee one row per <S.Status, DT.scheduledstartdate , DT.actualstartdate, DT.scheduledenddate> tuple (ignoring the syntax issues with the missing commas).

Comment: @LukStorms Thank you for the help! I get confused on this sometimes since I am still new to sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expose the `Detail` and `Value` columns via the `DT` inline table. Something like the following should do it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       S.Status, 
       DT.scheduledstartdate 
       DT.actualstartdate
       DT.scheduledenddate
       MAX(CASE DT.Detail WHEN 'Note' THEN DT.Value END) Notes,
       MAX(CASE DT.Detail WHEN 'Late' THEN DT.[Value] END) Reason,
FROM dbo.View_RptMod S 

 JOIN [dbo].[View_Phase] P ON P.Studyd = S.Studyd 
 JOIN [dbo].[View_Prop] VP ON VP.[Studyd] = S.Studyd

 JOIN 
 (SELECT [RowId],[actualstartdate],[scheduledstartdate],[scheduledenddate],[comments], DD.Value, DD.Detail
 FROM [dbo].[DataInfo] DT  
 JOIN (SELECT [RowId],[Detail],[Value] FROM dbo.DataDetail) DD ON DD.RowId = DT.RowId
 WHERE [scheduledstartdate] IS NOT NULL) DT
 ON DT.PhaseRowId = P.phaserowid
```

Comment: Thank you! Still a bit new to SQL but will take note on this for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of syntax errors in your query:

- The one that is causing that error is that `DD` is within a derived table, so is not visible to the outer scope
- It is not necessary to put those joins in derived tables anyway
- Missing and extra commas
- `DISTINCT` but no `GROUP BY`, you must have a `GROUP BY` for all non-aggregated columns. Generally, `DISTINCT` is the wrong tool for most jobs, and its presence is a code smell

```sql
SELECT
    S.Status, 
    DT.scheduledstartdate 
    DT.actualstartdate
    DT.scheduledenddate
    MAX(CASE DD.Detail WHEN 'Note' THEN DD.Value END) Notes,
    MAX(CASE DD.Detail WHEN 'Late' THEN DD.[Value] END) Reason,
FROM
    dbo.View_RptMod S 
JOIN 
    [dbo].[View_Phase] P ON P.Studyd = S.Studyd 
JOIN 
    [dbo].[View_Prop] VP ON VP.[Studyd] = S.Studyd
JOIN 
    [dbo].[DataInfo] DT ON DT.PhaseRowId = P.phaserowid
JOIN
    dbo.DataDetail DD ON DD.RowId = DT.RowId
                     AND DT.[scheduledstartdate] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    S.Status, 
    DT.scheduledstartdate 
    DT.actualstartdate
    DT.scheduledenddate;
```

You probably need to add primary keys to the `GROUP BY` clause also